# Recursive changing variables - Sierpinski carpet

Tags: java, image, recursion

I'm having some problems whit drawing a sierpinski carpet, and would apreciate any help.

I was able to define the stoping condition, draw the central rectangle, and recursively, draw the next level of the image, all while keeping count.

It just so happens that I can only draw on the top left side. I'd say I'm confusing variables, but I can't seem to figure it out. Would apreciate any help

This is the part of the code where i'm having problems.

```
    int smallerWidth = newWidth / 3;
    int smallerHeight = newHeight / 3;

    int sX = 0;
    int sY = 0;
    if (currentDeep > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            sX = width / 9 + (i * 3 * (width / 9));
            sY = height / 9;
            g.fillRect(sX, sY, smallerWidth, smallerHeight);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                sY = height / 9 + (j * 3 * (height / 9));
                g.fillRect(sX, sY, smallerWidth, smallerHeight);
            }
        }
        return 1 + printSquares(g, sX, sY, newWidth, newHeight, currentDeep 
                                                  - 1);
    } else
        return 1;
}
```

This is the full code
https://pastebin.com/WPJ5tG8w

In sum my question is. What should I change/create in order for my program to draw the remaining 7 squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is, that you are trying to perform actions for multiple layers of the recursion at once. Normally, in the recursion, you would only paint the Quadrado central, calculate the sizes and coordinates of the smaller rectangles, and call the method recursively. That way you ensure that the recursive calls do not influence the stuff that is already there.

```
private int printSquares(Graphics g, int xi, int yi, int width, int height, int currentDeep) {
    //Quadrado central
    int newWidth = width / 3;
    int newHeight = height / 3;
    int x = (width / 3) + xi;
    int y = (height / 3) + yi;
    g.fillRect(x, y, newWidth, newHeight);

    int sX = 0;
    int sY = 0;
    if (currentDeep > 1) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //This is the position of each of the small rectangles
                sX = i * (width / 3) + xi;
                sY = j * (height / 3) + yi;

                // Call the method recursively in order to draw the smaller rectangles
                sum += printSquares(g, sX, sY, newWidth, newHeight, currentDeep - 1);
            }
        }
        return 1 + sum;
    } else
        return 1;
}
```

I hope, this resolves you issue.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand correctly. By the line 
sum += printSquares(g, sX, sY, newWidth, newHeight, currentDeep - 1);
what you did was draw a new square around each of the New squares, 

Then, later, you return the number of squares drawed, but just after all the squares were drawn. 

It also seems I had to much variables,

Ty for the help, I apreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to mark the question as solved if my answer solves your question. Otherwise others might try to solve it, too.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is ok. This is amazing code. I took the liberty to complete this with the original code provided in the question and added the code that fixed it that Illedhar recommended as a added method. Here it is. Thank you for sharing this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class sierpinskicarpet {
 
   public static Color BACKGROUNDCOLOR = new Color(0, 0, 150);
   public static Color FOREGROUNDCOLOR = new Color(255, 180, 0);
 
    // Padrao = 5, alterado
   public static int DEEP = 10;
 
    /**
     * Build the frame and shows it
     */
   public sierpinskicarpet(int deep) {
   
        // the frame and title
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("...: Recursive Squares with deep " + deep + " :...");
   
        // Dispose frame on click on close button
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   
        // set size and center frame on screen
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   
        // add print area occupying all the frame content area
      frame.add(new PrintArea(deep));
   
        // put frame visible
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
 
    /**
     * Main method
     */
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // launch for 1 to DEEP squares frames
               for (int i = DEEP; i >= 1; --i) {
                    // build a new object each time: objects will run
                    // independently
                  new sierpinskicarpet(i);
               }
            
            }
         });
   }
}
 
/**
 * Our print area is, in fact, a label extended with the paint squares behavior
 */
class PrintArea extends JLabel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    // local deep variable, will keep the registered deep for this the print
    // area
   int deep;
 
    /**
     * constructor
     */
   public PrintArea(int deep) {
        // call super, that is JLabel, constructor
      super();
   
        // set background color and set as well opaque to allow the background
        // to be visible
      setBackground(sierpinskicarpet.BACKGROUNDCOLOR);
      setOpaque(true);
   
        // save the deep
      this.deep = deep;
   }
 
    /**
     * paint method, called by JVM, when it is needed to update the PrintArea
     */
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // call paint from the JLABEL, draws the background of the PrintArea
      super.paint(g);
   
        // set drawing color
      g.setColor(sierpinskicarpet.FOREGROUNDCOLOR);
   
        // call the amazing print square method
      int n = printSquares(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this.deep);
   
        // put to the world how much squares we printed
      System.out.println("Deep = " + deep + ", squares painted: " + n);
   }
 
    /**
     * Auxiliary method that will to the work. It must print a square with 1/3
     * of the length of the frame and at the center and if not the bottom level
     * ask to do the same for each of the other 8 square with 1/3 of length but
     * called with the new deep
     */
   private int printSquares(Graphics g, int xi, int yi, int width, int height, int currentDeep) {
    //Quadrado central
      int newWidth = width / 3;
      int newHeight = height / 3;
      int x = (width / 3) + xi;
      int y = (height / 3) + yi;
      g.fillRect(x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
   
      int sX = 0;
      int sY = 0;
      if (currentDeep > 1) {
         int sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //This is the position of each of the small rectangles
               sX = i * (width / 3) + xi;
               sY = j * (height / 3) + yi;
            
                // Call the method recursively in order to draw the smaller rectangles
               sum += printSquares(g, sX, sY, newWidth, newHeight, currentDeep - 1);
            }
         }
         return 1 + sum;
      } else
         return 1;
   
   }
}

/*
Works Cited:
Recursive changing variables - sierpinski carpet. Stack Overflow. Retrieved May 4, 2022, 
from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945862/recursive-changing-variables-sierpinski-carpet
*/
```